# Sqlite data storage

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, binary

I am running a sqlite command

```
SELECT address FROM Locations WHERE address='hola'
```

On a data base table

[image: table]

[image: table structure]

The output is only one row even though the result should be 3 rows
[image: result]

This is the Python 3 code I ran to insert values in the DB:

```
st = "hola"
st1 = st.encode()
st2 =memoryview(st1)

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)''',(st,))
cur.execute('''
INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)''',(st1,))
cur.execute('''
INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)''',(st2,))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: What does `SELECT *, typeof(address) FROM Locations` give you? `text` for all three, or are two of them `blob`?

Comment: text , blob ,blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using your sample python code to populate a table in a database, I ran this query:

```
sqlite> select *, typeof(address) from locations;
id          address     typeof(address)
----------  ----------  ---------------
1           hola        text           
2           hola        blob           
3           hola        blob
```

Two of the values you're inserting are stored as blobs, one as a text string.

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) on how values of different types are compared:

> A TEXT value is less than a BLOB value.

That is to say, a string like `'hola'` will never be equal to a blob, even if the underlying bytes of the string are identical to the bytes in the blob. That's why only one value is being returned by your `SELECT`.

Comment: is there a way to select the blob field. also why TEXT field is not giving error when blob is entered

Comment: @JohnFrancis Sqlite uses dynamic typing; it's perfectly fine to store a blob in a column with a different affinity. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html is mandatory reading for understanding how sqlite works. (And `SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE address = X'686F6C61'` is one way - that uses a blob literal.  But better is to just not store strings as blobs in the first place, but as text values)

Answer (score 1):

This is a charset problem.
st it is ISO charset
st1 and st2 it is UTF-8 charset.

And your query is in ISO charset format.

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing comments

```
""" I'm multi-line comment"""
```

with strings

```
"I'm a string"
```

I suggest you to modify your code as follows

```
st = "hola"
st1 = st.encode()
st2 =memoryview(st1)

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)',(st,))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)',(st1,))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Locations(address)VALUES(?)',(st2,))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: The value are entered properly with my python code into DB table. The problem is the sqlite command display only 1st row as output