# Advantage of memoryview and bytestring

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I have a source code from an on-line course that I have enrolled in ;using the follow sqlite command in python3 script

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Locations (address, geodata)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', (memoryview(address.encode()), memoryview(data.encode()) ) )
```

the **address is string** and **geodata is json** loaded using **json.loads()**
the fields in the table are both of TEXT in sqlite
I want to know what is the advantage of using memoryview(address.encode()) over just using address.encode() or just plain address?

Comment: None. In fact, you probably *don't* want to do that, because the values will be saved as blobs, not strings, which will cause all sorts of brokenness later when you try to compare them to strings.

Comment: See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790092/sqlite-data-storage/) and my answer to it for an example of how it can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Infact that was my question which you have answered yesterday